# Probabilistic regression on outliers

Tags: probability, regression

I have a given data set $D = \{ x_i, y_i \}_{i=1}^n$ for a **regression problem**. When I plot the data, it looks like there is an **underlying parabola** (2nd
order linear model) and some outliers.

I want to design an approach using a **probabilistic model** with a latent binary variable $\{ 0,1 \}$ indicating whether a data point is an outlier or not.

Currently I have no idea what I could do, what would the parameters be in this cause and how are they optimized? Is Expectation Maximization an idea?

Comment: Are there known outliers in your data? Why isn't using the $\frac{3}{2} IQR$ cutoff sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use robust regression.  It is simpler and downweights the outliers.

Comment: But this doesn't involve a probabilistic model, does it?

Comment: Why do you want a probabilistic model for outliers?

Comment: @MichaelChernick : Your suggestion makes sense only if outliers are bad.  What if the whole purpose is to find outliers?  The outliers may be the places where you should drill for oil.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Mahoni said that the model fit a quadratic function except for a few outliers.  That indicates that the outliers were hurting the fit.  But if you want to detect the outliers the larger residuals from a robust regression fit will be the outliers.